# How to make nested routes in react-router work?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

It seems that when you nest routes it does not display the page. For normal routes, I have no problems with it.

I have imported the components used for this. I have also imported the needed components for the routes.

```
import {Router, Route, browserHistory, Link, IndexRoute} from "react-router";
```

Here is a sample of my code:

```
ReactDOM.render((
<Router history = {browserHistory}>
    <Route path = "/" component = {Root}>
        <IndexRoute component = {Home} />
        <Route path = "/home" component = {Home} />
        <Route path = "/user" component = {User} />
        <Route path = "/characters" component = {Characters} />
        <Route path = "/characters/gen-1" component = {GenOne} />
    </Route>
</Router>), document.getElementById('wrapper'));
```

I have success in displaying the nested page if I do this code but when I refresh, I got errors on the console.

```
ReactDOM.render((
<Router history = {browserHistory}>
    <Route path = "/" component = {Root}>
        <IndexRoute component = {Home} />
        <Route path = "/home" component = {Home} />
        <Route path = "/user" component = {User} />
        <Route path = "/characters/" component = {Characters} />
            <Route path="/characters/gen-1" component={GenOne}>
        </Route>
    </Route>
</Router>), document.getElementById('wrapper'));
```

These are the errors:
[image]

I am using react-router version: 2.8.1.
Can anybody please point out or suggest what is the correct way to do nested routing? Any example would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hello - would you be able to post the errors you had in console?  Also, what version of react-router are you using?

Comment: @bmartin I already posted the screenshot and the react-router version on the description above.

Comment: did you try removing the 'characters/' part of the path in the nested Route?

Comment: @Sebastianb yes, I have also tried removing it.